# How do I make an interuptable program that deals with a heavy computational load?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that deals with a heavy computational load in an iterative fashion. I want to be able to interrupt the program and restart.

I have built a simple GUI using Tkinter to allow the iterative loop to be interrupted using an "after_cancel". This works fine in testing with a low computational load, but under a high computational load, the program does not respond to the button click that is meant to do the "after_cancel".

For simplicity's sake, I have replaced the program with fibonacci. The effect is the same (after a while).

How do I design this so that the "Stop" button remains responsive?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        self.master = master

        self.quitter = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitter.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.starter = Button(self.frame, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.starter.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.stopper = Button(self.frame, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stopper.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.counter = 0

    def start(self):
        print((fibonacci(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.afterid = self.master.after(1, self.start)

    def stop(self):
        print('Stop')
        self.master.after_cancel(self.afterid)


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fibonacci` function will run on your GUI thread if you call it from a widget callback. To avoid freezing your GUI, run `fibonacci` on a separate thread and set a flag to stop its execution:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time


def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        self.master = master

        self.quitter = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitter.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.starter = Button(self.frame, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.starter.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.stopper = Button(self.frame, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stopper.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.counter = 0
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.start_fibonacci).start()

    def start_fibonacci(self):
        while self.running:
            print(fibonacci(self.counter))
            self.counter += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        print('Stop')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Fibonacci")
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the mainprog function, you compute the fibonacci once, and then register an alarm callback as self.mainprog, that is called after 1 ms. In other words, there is an interval time between each call to fibonacci function. And your stopprog button could only respond your in the interval time, when the control right is idle.

Under a high computational load, the execution right is always retained by your task (in ONE call of fibonacci function). As a result, no button could respond you.

You would better implement your tast(such as fibonacci computation) in a multi-thread or multi-process manner to avoid this issue.